# I can not get an image of the URL found with XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to get a image url through XmlHttpRequest and use it like 'src' attribute of a 'img' tag. That is my plan:

```
function populaLista() {

var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/artes');

ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = ourRequest.responseText.toString();
    var jsonResposta = JSON.parse(ourData);

    if (ourData.length > 0) {

        document.getElementById("paragrafo1").innerHTML = jsonResposta.url;

        var tabela = document.createElement("TABLE");
        var corpoTabela = document.createElement("TBODY");
        var tr = document.createElement("TR");
        var td = document.createElement("TD");
        var imagem = document.createElement("IMG");
        var urlImg = document.createTextNode(jsonResposta.url).toString();
    //  var urlImg = "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/6310ed61231533.Y3JvcCwyNjM1LDIwNjIsMjI3LDA.jpg";

        document.getElementById("paragrafo").innerHTML = typeof urlImg;

        imagem.setAttribute("src",urlImg);
        td.appendChild(imagem);
        tr.appendChild(td);
        corpoTabela.appendChild(tr);
        tabela.appendChild(corpoTabela);

        document.getElementById("tabeladeImagens").appendChild(tabela);

    } else {
        document.getElementById("paragrafo").innerHTML = "item não encontrado";
    }

};
ourRequest.send();
```

The problem is: when I use the result of my request on my img tag, I can't see the image, but if I use the same url in a string var that I created I can see normally.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body onload="populaLista()">

    <p id="paragrafo"></p>
    <p id="paragrafo1"></p>

    <div id="tabeladeImagens" class="logoHome"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The json response:

```
{id : 38, url : "//mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/6310ed61231533.Y3JvcCwyNjM1LDIwNjIsMjI3LDA.jpg"}
```

Comment: What do you see in browser dev tools network regarding that image url request?

Comment: does `ourRequest.onload` even run?

Comment: The message of dev tools is: Failed to load http://localhost:8080/artes: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8083' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ourRequest.onload run in IDE but dont in browser.